# Are these C notes a slur or a tie?

Tags: theory, piano, notation, slurs

On the bass clef, there are 2 `C` notes. I think it is a [tie (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music)) and they should be played once for 6 beats. Am I correct? Or do I have to play the C twice, 3 beats each?

[image: notes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a tie. You have to play the C once and hold it for 6 quarters.

To tell the difference, keep in mind that slurs are used between different notes and ties are used between the same notes. For instance:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not always easy to tell, but here we are definitely talking about a tie.  How to distinguish?  A tie is sole functional and can *only* connect equal pitches (there is the tricky exception of a tie connecting *enharmonically* equivalent notes in a modulation but the execution would be to *hold* the note without noticeable intonation correction).

Does that mean that any bow connecting two identical notes is a tie?  By no means.  If the first note has any duration modifying sign (staccato, staccatissimo, tenuto, portato), this cannot be a tie.  If the second note has any accent mark, it's not an isolated note.  Duration modifiers are suspicious but not complete evidence: least suspicious is likely a staccato that may halve the duration value of second note part.

So what happens when we don't have a tie?  We have a slur.  Where it isn't solely an execution mark (string instruments are instructed not to change bowing direction, and for strings one would not really write a non-tieing slur without a tenuto mark or similar), it indicates connected execution.  Connecting two notes of same pitch closely is almost the same as a tie but not completely: is this a melodic phrase with two notes?  Like, are there similar slurs used as phrasing in the vicinity that connect *unequal* notes?

Now if we take a look at your excerpt, we have whole-measure notes connected across the bar line: that's not really melodic (though it could be if the two measures before were also connected but of different pitch).  But the complete clincher in your case is that there is *another* outer bowline across the notes that clearly indicates legato phrasing.

So the *phrasing* question already *has* an authoritive answer.  The bow connecting only the two C4 notes consequently has to be about something else.  So it's a tie.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some music engravers that don't follow this practice, the normal practice is that a tie begins horizontally slightly after the earlier note, and ends horizontally slightly before the following note, while the starting and ending horizontal positions of a slur would extend between the centers of the first and last involved noteheads.  The pictured marking fits the former description, and is thus a tie.